# Android ActionBar Tab Style

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs, android-styles

I know there are ample questions on this subject but I can't get it to work the color is staying the default blue. I'm trying to change the highlight color of the tabs. I've mainly followed this tutorial (http://blog.alwold.com/2013/08/28/styling-tabs-in-the-android-action-bar/).

Now in my `values/styles.xml` I have the following code:

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarWithoutTitle</item>
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

Apart from that I have a drawable state list plus two others setting some colours. Most importantly I have set the theme in my AndroidManifest.xml (AppBaseTheme) like so:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.stevesandco.miajournal.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also understand that in the values-v11 and values-v14 folders, the styles corresponding to the android version should also be added. The only problem is that when adding `<item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>` to `values-v14\styles.xml` the app crashes. I'm not sure whether I'm missing something it could be that it's a simple thing that I might have forgot.

`values-v11\styles.xml`:

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```

`values-v14\styles.xml`:

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>
```